# Prove $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}-\ln\left(\frac{\left(1+n\right)}{n}\right)\right)\:$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Prove $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}-\ln\left(\frac{\left(1+n\right)}{n}\right)\right)\:$ converges

I tried using taylor expansion and Cauchy condensation test, but got stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: That is (one of) the definition(s) of Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Taylor expansion of the logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series), for $n\geq 1$:
$$\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n} +O(n^{-2}).$$
The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}=\frac12$